# Reversing 1-D array

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to reverse a 1-D array which contains a list of files. I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360091/how-to-reverse-array-in-bash-onliner-for-loop
to be the code. But this is not quite working for me.

```
for (( i=${#FILES_dcn[@]}-1,j=0 ;i>=0;i--,j++ ));
do

  dcnarray[j] = ${FILES_dcn[i]}

done
```

The values are not getting copied when I echo the arrays onto a file. Why is that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you trim the spaces around the `=` it will work fine:

```
dcnarray[j]=${FILES_dcn[i]}
```

Answer (score 3):

There must be no space around `=` in variable assignments.

---

BTW, with `zsh`:

```
dcnarray=("${(@Oa)FILES_dcn}")
```